# C++ creating sorted vector from map

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, dictionary

I'm trying to create a sorted `vector` from a `map`, sorted according to a value that isn't the map's key.
The map value is `block` object, and I want the vector to be sorted according to `size`, attribute of `block`.
My code:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct block {
    string data;
    int size;
};

struct vecotrCompare {
    bool operator()(pair<const string, block*> &left,
      pair<const string, block*> &right) {
        return left.second -> size < right.second -> size;
    }
};

int main() {
    map<const string, block*> myMap;
    vector<pair<const string, block*> > myVector(
      myMap.begin(), myMap.end());
    sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), vecotrCompare());
}
```

The `sort(...)` line can't compile, and I'm getting a compile-error:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(vecotrCompare) (std::pair<const
  std::basic_string<char>, block*>&, const std::pair<const
  std::basic_string<char>, block*>&)’
```

Comment: `required from here` is only part of the error, and the most useless part at that.

Comment: always post the full error

Comment: Anyway, you can't have non-copyable objects (like a pair of a `const` something) in a vector. It's redundant in the map, and won't work outside of that.

Comment: What part of `error: no match for call to ‘(vecotrCompare)` is hard to understand...? IMHO it says all you need to know.

Comment: Any particular reason you spelt `vector` wrong?

Comment: Good job! You've completely changed the error and the reason you're seeing it by getting rid of the `const&` from `vecotrCompare::operator()`'s arguments. Add the `const&` back in, and you'll run into the next error, which I've explained in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements in a `vector` need to be MoveAssignable or CopyAssignable. A `pair<const string, block*>` is neither due to the `const string`. Change that to `string` and your code compiles.

```
map<string, block*> myMap;
vector<pair<string, block*> > myVector(myMap.begin(), myMap.end());
```

Also change your comparator so that the argument types are `const&`

```
struct vecotrCompare {
    bool operator()(pair< string, block*> const&left, 
                    pair< string, block*> const&right) const {
        return left.second -> size < right.second -> size;
    }
};
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac4eb97cd85908eb)

---

The second part about the arguments needing to be `const&` is actually not a requirement. From *§25.1/9*

> The `BinaryPredicate` parameter is used whenever an algorithm expects a function object that when applied to the result of dereferencing two corresponding iterators or to dereferencing an iterator and type `T` when `T` is part of the signature returns a value testable as `true`. In other words, if an algorithm takes `BinaryPredicate binary_pred` as its argument and `first1` and `first2` as its iterator arguments, it should work correctly in the construct `binary_pred(*first1, *first2)` contextually converted to `bool` (Clause 4). `BinaryPredicate` always takes the first iterator’s `value_type` as its first argument, that is, in those cases when `T` value is part of the signature, it should work correctly in the construct `binary_pred(*first1, value)` contextually converted to `bool` (Clause 4). **`binary_pred` shall not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterators**.

So the standard never mentions that the functor's argument types *must be* `const&`, but libstdc++ seems to be passing temporaries to the functor and the code [doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/236e36bc2fdc7bdf) unless you add the `const&` (looks like this has been fixed in gcc-4.9).

On the other hand, both libc++ and VS2013 [handle the case](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b572073dca6a04c) where the arguments are not `const&` correctly.

Comment: Almost; the OP took away the `const` from the functor's argument types, for no apparent reason. He needs to add it back in.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No freaking wonder! I knew the code compiled the first time I tried it. Just copy-pasted his code again and retried to make sure there wasn't anything I'd tweaked while messing with it, and of course, it wouldn't compile anymore!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the change suggested by @Praetorian, you should add some `const` in `vectorCompare::operator()`.

```
struct vecotrCompare {
    bool operator()(pair<const string, block*> const& left,
                    pair<const string, block*> const& right) const {
        return left.second -> size < right.second -> size;
    }
};
```

Here's the documentation on the requirements of `comp` from
 http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/.

comp

> Binary function that accepts two elements in the range as arguments, and returns a value convertible to bool. The value returned indicates whether the element passed as first argument is considered to go before the second in the specific strict weak ordering it defines.
>
> The function shall not modify any of its arguments.
>
> This can either be a function pointer or a function object.

Some compilers force the argument types to be `const&` or an object passed by value. Others work with a reference.

Comment: Explain _why_, instead of just dumping code. It is because `sort` provides some temporaries (rvalues) to the comparator, and these do not bind to non-`const` ref.

Comment: `The function shall not modify any of its arguments implies that types of the argument [etc]` No, it doesn't. That is not the reason.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In that case, I am missing some important aspect of this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit To be fair, a quick look through the requirements at the beginning of §25.1 doesn't reveal anything other than the predicate should not modify the arguments. And [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) also says the arguments need not be `const&`. This seems like an implementation specific issue, unless there's some requirement I missed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yep, it is. libc++ [handles the sort](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b572073dca6a04c) even if the predicate arguments aren't `const&`. And so does VS2013, who would've thunk!

Comment: @Praetorian g++ 4.7.3, which is what I have on my desktop, doesn't compile without the `const`. Is g++ 4.7.3 behind the times in this regard?

Comment: @Praetorian: No, I mean, a requirement that the arguments not be modified is _not_ the same as a requirement that the arguments be of `const` type. That is, _the cited rule is not relevant_. That you can get the sort to work with non-`const` arguments in alternative standard library implementations only further solidifies my claim that this answer is not quite correct. The cause of the problem is that libstdc++ is passing temporaries in, as I said. Your own answer agrees with me on all of this.

Comment: @RSahu It's fixed in gcc-4.9. And I agree with Lightness' last comment. You should change the last sentence in your answer, it's incorrect. The predicate shall not modify its arguments means exactly what it says, it doesn't imply that the function must take the elements by value or `const&`